# The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \min_{k\le n}\{\alpha k\}$ for irrational $\alpha$

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. 
For every $n$ let $z_n$ be the integer closest to the number $\alpha n$. Then we can define
$$A(\alpha):= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\alpha n - z_n|.$$

We can also define somewhat similar quantity
$$B(\alpha):= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\alpha n - \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor \right).$$

$A(\alpha)$ and $B(\alpha)$ are sums of non-negative numbers, so the values can be real numbers of $+\infty$.

---

**EDIT:** In fact, the above sums are clearly both equal to $+\infty$, since $n \alpha$ will be infinitely often arbitrarily close to and integer (and also to a number of the form $k+\frac12$, $k\in\mathbb Z$). See, for example, [Multiples of an irrational number forming a dense subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset) (and several other posts on MSE).

I have missed this obvious fact when posting the question. However the sums $A'(\alpha)$ and $B'(\alpha)$ described below might still be interesting.

I left here the part about $A(\alpha)$ and $B(\alpha)$, since some users already posted some comments about these sums. If I edited the first part of the post away, those comments would not make sense.

---

We can also make modifications where we replace the sequence with monotone sequences:
$$
\begin{align*}
A'(\alpha):=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \min_{k\le n}|\alpha k - z_k|;\\
B'(\alpha):=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \min_{k\le n} \left(\alpha k - \lfloor \alpha k \rfloor\right).\\
\end{align*}
$$

In some sense, these quantities tell us how far $\alpha$ is from rational numbers. (The monotone versions seem more closely related to question whether $\alpha$ is rational or irrational, since for rational $\alpha$ all but finitely many terms are zero, so the sum must be finite.)

My question is:

- Were the numbers $A'(\alpha)$, $B'(\alpha)$ studied somewhere?
- Can they be calculated for some specific irrational numbers? For example, can we calculate them for $\alpha=\ln 2$, $\alpha=\sqrt2$, $\alpha=e$, $\alpha=\pi$ or some other well-know irrational numbers?
- Do we get $A'(\alpha)=\infty$ or $B'(\alpha)=\infty$ for some numbers? If yes, can such numbers be characterized?
- Are they related to [irrationality measure](https://www.google.com/search?q=irrationality+measure) or some other ways to measure [how irrational](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53724/are-some-numbers-more-irrational-than-others) a given number $\alpha$ is?

---

To explain what lead me to these sums: I was thinking about question whether there is a counterexample to [Minkowski's theorem](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_enSK500SK500&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=minkowski%20theorem%20lattice) for unbounded sets. (Such question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249608/boundedness-condition-of-minkowskis-theorem). In the meantime I learned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90158/minkowskis-theorem-in-lang-algebraic-number-theory/90161#90161) that such example cannot be found.)
So I was trying to take a line $y=\alpha x$ which does not contain any lattice points. I tried to replace the segments of this line by wider rectangles - this lead me to try to compute how wide rectangles I can add without hitting some lattice point. This is related to the question how far are the points $(n,n\alpha)$ from lattice points.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [Pisot numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I meant to evaluate them. (I.e., if they are $+\infty$ for each $\alpha$, that would answer my question.) However, I do not think that $A'(\alpha)$ and $B'(\alpha)$ are always infinite.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ should be infinite for all nonintegral $\alpha$ (they are periodic for $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$).  The other two sums are more interesting (indeed)

Comment: It is not obvious to me that $A(\alpha)$ is well-defined. Even if $n$ is the denominator of a convergent of the continued fraction of $\alpha$ then $|\alpha n-z_n|$ should behave like $\frac{1}{n}$, leading to a divergent sum.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have added a note explicitly stating that the values $+\infty$ are allowed to my post. Other than the value can be infinite, I guess they are well-defined.

Comment: I bet you can compute these sums for simple quadratic irrationals such as the golden ratio.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Exactly. The same for $A'(\alpha)$. (I've tried to compute $A'(\sqrt{2})$... haha)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bivec}[2]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \\ #2 \end{bmatrix}}$
Excavating. Still the series for $A'(\alpha)$ and $B'(\alpha)$ both diverge always.

Let $\alpha=[a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots]$ be the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations) expansion of $\alpha$, and $p_n/q_n$ be its $n$-th convergent:
$$\bivec{p_{-1}}{q_{-1}}=\bivec{1}{0},\ \bivec{p_0}{q_0}=\bivec{a_0}{1},\ \bivec{p_n}{q_n}=a_n\bivec{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}+\bivec{p_{n-2}}{q_{n-2}}.$$
Then for $r\geqslant 0$ and $q_r\leqslant n<q_{r+1}$ we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) $\displaystyle\min_{k\leqslant n}|\alpha k-z_k|=|\alpha q_r-p_r|$, which gives
$$A'(\alpha)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(q_{n+1}-q_n)\cdot|\alpha q_n-p_n|\geqslant\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{q_{n+1}+q_n}$$
by "Theorem 5" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems). But $r_n=q_{n+1}/q_n$ can't converge to $1$ because $r_n=a_{n+1}+1/r_{n-1}$.

(Therefore $\dfrac{q_{n+1}-q_n}{q_{n+1}+q_n}=\dfrac{r_n-1}{r_n+1}$ can't converge to $0$.)

Thus $A'(\alpha)=+\infty$ for any (irrational) $\alpha$, and therefore $B'(\alpha)=+\infty$ too.